# JavaScript calculation with tax - keeps returning NaN

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, calculation

In my program, I am trying to calculate the cost of several products chosen by the user. The subtotal function works just fine, but the total (after taxes) calculation is not working and keeps returning NaN. I've tried a variety of placements of parseInt, parseFloat, and Number, but still can't seem to figure it out. TYIA

JavaScript

```
 $('#kitChoices').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

 function calcPrice() {
  var price = 0;
  $("input[type=radio][data-price]:checked").each(function(i, el) {
    price += +$(el).data("price");
  });
  $("#price").text(price);
}

calcPrice();

function total_price(){
  const TAXRATE = 0.06;
  var finalCost = (price * TAXRATE);
  $("#totalPrice").text(finalCost);
}

total_price();

...

});
```

HTML- probably wont function without full code, but here you go.

```
<!--HELP ZONE (Where functions show up)--------------------------------------------->   
  <div id="submit">

      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Click to calculate total"  /><br><br>
        
         <p id="total">Subtotal: $<span id="price"></span><br><br>

         <!--HELP ZONE-->   
        Total: $<span id="totalPrice"></span>
        </p>

            <br>

        <p class="p2">Win one of the following prizes with purchase:</p>

        <p id="hint">

        <p id="prizeButton"></p>
        

        <button id="freeItem" style="display:none">Prize</button>
         <p id="free_item"></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: your radio buttons have no value ? please add this part too. HTML forms are really more simple to code than what you have done!

Answer (score 0):

This is because price is undefined. You would need to move the var price declaration to the outside of the calcPrice function. Also this is not related but I'm pretty sure the final cost is the cost + the cost*TAXRATE so this would be better var finalCost = price + (price * TAXRATE);